# Mirrored circle not showing in edit-mode

Tags: modeling

I am using Blender 2.78. I enabled "Display modifier" but it is still not visible in editmode.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your problem to make it more clear and easier to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Vertices not visible ....[image]

vertices now visible in edit mode .....
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mirrored vertices aren't shown in edit mode, as long as there are no faces.

[image: vertices only shown when having faces]

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, you never see the verticles of the mirrored part, 
as that would be highly confusing. 
Those verticles (the mesh) doesnt exist, so you dont see the editable parts of the mesh but you can see the mirror aplied to it. You can only alter the left side of your circle and thus you see that in mesh edit mode.

it is though possible after you aplied the mirror to mirror X editing, and edit both sides of your mirror.

Answer (score -1):

Thank all for your answer.

I found another solution:

1. Add Circle
2. (Modifier) Mirror
3. Choose wireframe
4. Go *Edit Mode*
5. Move (G-key)

Now it is visible in editmode and objectmode.

Comment: It's not clear what you were asking, what you want to achieve or how this answers solves the problem. Could you please edit them both and provide a little more insight, perhaps some screenshots too. IT may help other users in the future